# Bash environment variable to include path of c libraries

Tags: build, include

I built a C library (compiled from source) below my home folder and now I have to build a new package that depends on that library. When running the configure script I get the error
`configure: error: The required <package> library was not found.`

Is there an environment variable  I can edit to make my script search the library's path?

I already tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should set `C_INCLUDE_PATH`  or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, for C or C++ respectively.

More information is available [gcc documentation](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html)

Comment: Thanks. Before seeing your answer I edited the configure script for the new package to make it look in the directory I needed.